# Regex: Delete all lines before STRING, except one particular line

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I want to delete all the lines before `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but I want to keep the line that starts with: `$item_id =`

```
<?<!-- ÉTOILES R -->);
    
     $item_id = 1442 ; // Remplacez-le par votre identifiant de notation.
    
     // Si vous voulez que la note fonctionne avec les Rich-Snippets,
     // définit la classe d'évaluation sur l'une des valeurs suivantes :
     // produit, page, blog-post, post, front-post, article
     $rating_class = 'page';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**THE OUTPUT should be**

```
     $item_id = 1442 ; // Remplacez-le par votre identifiant de notation.

     <!DOCTYPE html>
```

**My regex fail:**

FIND: `(?s)\A(^.*)(<!DOCTYPE html>)(?!\$item_id =.*?id)`

REPLACE BY: `\3\2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\A[\s\S]*?(^\h*\$item_id.+\R)[\s\S]+?(?=\R<!DOCTYPE html>)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A              # beginning of file
[\s\S]*?        # 0 or more any character, not greedy
(               # group 1
  ^               # beginning of line
    \h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
    \$item_id       # literally $item_id
    .+              # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R              # any kind of linebreak
)               # end group 1
[\s\S]+?        # 1 or more any character, not greedy
(?=\R<!DOCTYPE html>)   # positive lookahead, make sure we have DOCTYPE after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something wrong?